# How to change the value tof the use tag in a svg file

Tags: qgis, c++, api, svg

I am working in C++/QT4.5 with the qgis c++ api 2.8.2

I have a svg file that contains different form tag by Id

When i want the first form i place the id name in the use xlink:href="#formname" ....

Is it possible to change dynamically the formname with qgis or display another form with the same svg file ?